# What is inner creator (objectinstance.new) in Java?

Tags: java

I came across something like

```
ArgProcessor argProcessor = runWebApp.new ArgProcessor(options);
```

This line is from the source of GWT. By digging into Java's grammar I found it to be (".new") inner creator.

But I didn't find any proper documentation about why exactly we need the inner creator.

How does this differ from a normal object/instance creator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is for creating an object of the inner class type.

for example: look at this

http://www.javabeat.net/tips/124-inner-classes-in-java.html

ie:

```
class Outer{

  final int z=10;

  class Inner extends HasStatic {
    static final int x = 3;
    static int y = 4;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Outer outer=new Outer();
    System.out.println(outer.new Inner().y);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `new` keyword in this example is called within the scope of the `runWebApp` instance.  This means that `runWebApp.class` contains an inner class called `ArgProcessor`.  This is the appropriate way to specify you are construction `ArgProcessor` within `runWebApp`, and not calling some other top level `ArgProcessor` class.

Note that the external assignment will have an instance of ArgProcessor, but it will be `runWebApp`'s instance of `ArgProcessor`, and not some other instance's `ArgProcessor` instance.  Occasionally, this is done to simulate an old style C++ `friend` interface between classes; however, there are other reasons why this might be done.  It basically allows a more fine grained approach than the standard `public`, `protected`, `default`, `private` interfaces available with the actual programming language.

Answer (score 0):

An inner class is a class defined in another class. If it is not static, each instance of an inner class has an implicit reference to the instance of the outer class. It can be accessed from within the inner class like this: `OuterClass.this`.

So, when you instantiate the inner class `InnerClass` from a non static method of the instance `outerObject` of the outer class `OuterClass`, the created instance `innerObject` has an implicit reference to `outerObject`. But when you want to do the same from somewhere outside of `OuterClass` (or from a static method), you have to specify the instance of `OuterClass` it will reference: you do that by calling `new` on the instance of the outer class.